# Saving images when using jsPDF in an iOS UIWebView

Tags: ios, image, uiwebview, jspdf

We have a web app (HTML5/CSS/JavaScript) that runs in a UIWebView inside of a native app on iOS. This particular web app is using jsPDF to generate an email and attach a pdf. We have only been using jsPDF for about six weeks, but everything is working well with one exception. The pdf document we are creating is a sales document, and we want to include a logo at the top of the page.

Right now, when we are in development mode (Safari 10.1.1 on Mac OS Sierra) everything works well . We create a new pdf object with jsPDF. Add text using pdf.text, add tables with pdf.autoTable, and add some HTML content with pdf.fromHTML. We also add one image (the logo) with pdf.addImage. All of this works great in Safari on the Mac, including the image. The image works wether we add it by referencing the file directly or whether we convert it to a Base64 image. We are able to save the pdf and it looks just like we want it to.

When we move to iOS, we aren't saving the file, we are creating it and attaching it to an email. Everything still works with one exception. The image is missing on iOS. Everything else is just as we want it.

We have tried generating image different ways to see if the iOS UIWebView can create it in the pdf. For instance, we've used Canvas2HTML with addHTML, and again things look good on the Mac, but the image is missing in the UIWebView within iOS.

Is there some trick to getting an image inserted into the pdf using jsPDF when you are in an iOS UIWebView? We need some help. We've run out of options. We are going to try and set things up so we can inspect the JavaScript console inside the UIWebView, but at this point it appears to me we may have an issue with jsPDF in a UIWebView. Surely someone else has run across this issue.

Thanks for any assistance you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the image had not loaded fully in iOS before it was inserted into the PDF. It did complete "on time" on the Mac. Adjusted the callback to make sure the image was fully loaded before inserting it into the pdf. Still having problems with the image being garbled, but it is now being inserted.